# Stack has not been tested with GHC versions above 9.0

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I wandet to run my Code. I get this Kind of "Error".

Stack has not been tested with GHC versions above 9.0, and using 9.2.5, this may fail
Stack has not been tested with Cabal versions above 3.4, but version 3.6.3.0 was found, this may fail

Do i have to download a new Version of GHC?

Comment: Sounds like you need to upgrade Stack itself. According to https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/blob/master/.github/workflows/unit-tests.yml, Stack 2.9.1 uses GHC 9.4.

Comment: I'd try running `stack upgrade` and `stack update`.